# Session destroy automatically in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

Hi I am new to Laravel and working on laravel 5.3. I have a session array I can see data is in session for the first time but when I refresh the page session get destroy or when i move to another page session destroy.

```
$userData = array(
            'userId'      => $result[0]->id,
            'username'    => $result[0]->name,
            'email'       => $result[0]->email
        );
$request->session()->set('userlogin', $userData);
print_r($request->session()->all());
```

Now when I print_r the session I can see the values in session and then when i print_r the session->all() in another controller of same controller the session is not more. In simple words session is saving and destroy automatically. 
Please help me out I have wasted 2 days can't figure out the problem.

sorry for bad english firt time on stackoverflow

config file is overhere

```
<?php
```

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
| cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
| correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
|
*/

'store' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,
```

];

Comment: Try use put instead of set

Comment: " set " is working as you can see when i do print_r it is working. but for the second time session destroy automatically

Comment: First go to https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session and try find 'set' to use

Comment: Yes I have gone through the document nicely set is not there put is there but issue is something else. Still not working

Comment: Show your config/session.php file in your question

Comment: @rad11 is completely right. use put or the helper function to store the value and try it again!

Comment: I use put and still it is not working

Comment: @rad11 config file is also added in question

Comment: Check whether your routes are wrapped within "web" middleware.Without that, your sessions will not persists.